# Real analysis: Riemann integral question

Tags: real-analysis

If we have:

Let $I := [a,b]$ and let $f: I\to\mathbb ℝ$ be continuous on $I$. Also let $J := [c,d]$ and let $u: J\to\mathbb ℝ$ be differentiable on $J$ and satisfy $u(J)\subseteq I$. Show that if $G: J\to\mathbb ℝ$ is defined by
 $$ G(x) :=\int_a^{u(x)} f(t)\,dt $$ 
for $x$ in $J$, then $G'(x) = (f \circ u)(x)u'(x)$ for all $x\in J$.

Can we just say use the Fundamental Thm of Calculus or do we need to break it up over two integrals?

Comment: I say 2 integrals because there is a constant in the limit

Comment: You might want to consider changing the title of your question. It doesn't seem very helpful if someone else is searching for an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you can use the FTC: since $\,f\,$ is continuous we know that

$$\int_a^{u(x)}f(t)\,dt=F(u(x))-F(a)$$

where $\,F\,$ is a primitive of $\,f\,$ on $\,[a,b]\;:\;\;F'(t)=f(t)\,\,,\,\forall\,\,t\in [a,b]\,$ , and thus applying the chain rule

$$G(x)=F(u(x))-F(a)\Longrightarrow G'(x)=F'(u(x))\cdot u'(x)=f(u(x))\cdot u'(x)$$